# Android: clicking the image in camera and show the image in dialogbox

Tags: android, android-camera, android-imageview, android-gallery, android-dialog

i m using a custom dialog with an `ImageView` and 2 `Button`.

1. first button to pick image from gallery
2. second button to click image from camera

i want to show the image in the `ImageView` of the dialog..

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Dialog();   
        }

        private void Dialog() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(editevent1.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.promote2);
            ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_camera);
            Button d=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            Button f=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button3);

            dialog.show();
            d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


                }
            });
            f.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent cameraintent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    startActivityForResult(cameraintent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                }
            });


            }


});



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if( requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
    {   
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_camera);
        image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture NOt taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);            
    }

}
```

please tell me how do i get the image in `ImageView` which is in `DialogBox` for both when picked from gallery and when clicked from camera. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure this can be done using a `Dialog` but instead of a custom dialog, try and use an Activity that has the `UI` of a dialog. To use an `Activity` as a dialog you need to define this in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

`<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />`

**EDIT for Comment**

1. If you used my suggestion (an `Activity` with the UI of a `Dialog` let's name it `DialogActivity` for our purposes), you do not have to do that since you can override the `onActivityResult` method in your `DialogActivity`.
2. If you have not used my suggestion or have used it but need to pass the taken image to another `Activity` either way. To pass an image that was taken by the camera app from one `Activity` to another, i believe the most efficient way is to pass in the `Intent` as a `String` the path of that image and access the path on the second `Activity`. Something like this:

In the first `Activity` (the caller `Activity`), let's call it A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("path", path); //The path is a String variable holding the path where the image was saved.
startActivity(i);
```

In the second `Activity` (the `Activity` being called), let's call it B:

```
String image_path = getIntent().getExtras().getString("path");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_path);
```

Comment: i have got the solution. but can you please tell how to take that image from this activity to another activity...

Answer (score 0):

I think you show your dialog box again.

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if( requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST)
        {   
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_camera);
            image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            **dialog.show();**


        }
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Picture NOt taken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);            
    }

}
```